# Cross Join with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data that looks like this:

| Date | Vendor | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Mickey Mouse | 100 |
| 2021-01-15 | Mickey Mouse | 150 |
| 2021-01-01 | Donald Duck | 100 |
| 2021-01-01 | Goofy | 100 |
| 2021-02-01 | Mickey Mouse | 200 |
| 2021-02-01 | Donald Duck | 200 |
| 2021-02-01 | Goofy | 200 |

And have some more data like this:

| Month | Vendor | Snack | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January 2021 | Mickey Mouse | Churros | 0.5 |
| January 2021 | Mickey Mouse | Funnel Cake | 0.25 |
| January 2021 | Mickey Mouse | Apples | 0.25 |
| January 2021 | Goofy | Churros | 0.34 |
| January 2021 | Goofy | Funnel Cake | 0.33 |
| January 2021 | Goofy | Water | 0.33 |

I would like to perform an operation using Pandas that yields the following:

| Date | Vendor | Snack | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Mickey Mouse | Churros | 50 |
| 2021-01-01 | Mickey Mouse | Funnel Cake | 25 |
| 2021-01-01 | Mickey Mouse | Apples | 25 |
| 2021-01-15 | Mickey Mouse | Churros | 75 |
| 2021-01-15 | Mickey Mouse | Funnel Cake | 37.5 |
| 2021-01-15 | Mickey Mouse | Apples | 37.5 |
| 2021-01-01 | Goofy | Churros | 34 |
| 2021-01-01 | Goofy | Funnel Cake | 33 |
| 2021-01-01 | Goofy | Water | 33 |
| 2021-01-01 | Donald Duck |  | 100 |
| 2021-02-01 | Donald Duck |  | 200 |
| 2021-02-01 | Mickey Mouse |  | 200 |
| 2021-02-01 | Goofy |  | 200 |

I know how to do this using cross joins in Redshift but can't quite nail down the syntax here using either `pd.merge` or `np.dot`. Here are the sample data frames:

```
revenue = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': [
        '2021-01-01',
        '2021-01-15',
        '2021-01-01',
        '2021-01-01',
        '2021-02-01',
        '2021-02-01',
        '2021-02-01',
        ],
    'Vendor': [
        'Mickey Mouse',
        'Mickey Mouse',
        'Donald Duck',
        'Goofy',
        'Mickey Mouse',
        'Donald Duck',
        'Goofy',
    ],
    'Revenue': [100,150,100,100,200,200,200,]
        })
breakdown = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month': [
        'January 2021',
        'January 2021',
        'January 2021',
        'January 2021',
        'January 2021',
        'January 2021',
    ],
    'Vendor': [
        'Mickey Mouse',
        'Mickey Mouse',
        'Mickey Mouse',
        'Goofy',
        'Goofy',
        'Goofy',
    ],
    'Snack': [
        'Churros',
        'Funnel Cake',
        'Apples',
        'Churros',
        'Funnel Cake',
        'Water',
    ],
    'Percentage': [0.5,0.25,0.25,0.34,0.33,0.33]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
breakdown["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(breakdown["Month"])
revenue["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(revenue["Date"])

x = pd.merge(
    breakdown.assign(
        y=breakdown["Month"].dt.year, m=breakdown["Month"].dt.month
    ),
    revenue.assign(y=revenue["Date"].dt.year, m=revenue["Date"].dt.month),
    on=["y", "m", "Vendor"],
    how="outer",
)
x["Revenue"] *= x["Percentage"].fillna(1)
print(x[["Date", "Vendor", "Snack", "Revenue"]].fillna(""))
```

Prints:

```
         Date        Vendor        Snack  Revenue
0  2021-01-01  Mickey Mouse      Churros     50.0
1  2021-01-15  Mickey Mouse      Churros     75.0
2  2021-01-01  Mickey Mouse  Funnel Cake     25.0
3  2021-01-15  Mickey Mouse  Funnel Cake     37.5
4  2021-01-01  Mickey Mouse       Apples     25.0
5  2021-01-15  Mickey Mouse       Apples     37.5
6  2021-01-01         Goofy      Churros     34.0
7  2021-01-01         Goofy  Funnel Cake     33.0
8  2021-01-01         Goofy        Water     33.0
9  2021-01-01   Donald Duck                 100.0
10 2021-02-01  Mickey Mouse                 200.0
11 2021-02-01   Donald Duck                 200.0
12 2021-02-01         Goofy                 200.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Convert the dates in `revenue` to reflect the string format of those in `breakdown`
- Merge the frames on revenue and vendor (outer merge to get the cross join effect)
- calculate the revenue by multiplying the existing revenue by percentage
- subselect the relevent columns

```
out = (
    revenue
    .assign(
        Month=pd.to_datetime(revenue["Date"]).dt.strftime("%B %Y")
    )
    .merge(breakdown, on=["Month", "Vendor"], how="outer")
    .assign(Revenue=lambda d: d["Revenue"] * d["Percentage"].fillna(1))
    .filter(["Date", "Vendor", "Snack", "Revenue"])
)
​
print(out)
          Date        Vendor        Snack  Revenue
0   2021-01-01  Mickey Mouse      Churros     50.0
1   2021-01-01  Mickey Mouse  Funnel Cake     25.0
2   2021-01-01  Mickey Mouse       Apples     25.0
3   2021-01-15  Mickey Mouse      Churros     75.0
4   2021-01-15  Mickey Mouse  Funnel Cake     37.5
5   2021-01-15  Mickey Mouse       Apples     37.5
6   2021-01-01   Donald Duck          NaN    100.0
7   2021-01-01         Goofy      Churros     34.0
8   2021-01-01         Goofy  Funnel Cake     33.0
9   2021-01-01         Goofy        Water     33.0
10  2021-02-01  Mickey Mouse          NaN    200.0
11  2021-02-01   Donald Duck          NaN    200.0
12  2021-02-01         Goofy          NaN    200.0
```